# IF condition for renaming a field to GDS

Tags: looker-studio

Several values in the form of numbers come to me in GDS. I would like to replace them with more understandable words by means of GDS.
For example: If number = '123345' display the "Main advertising campaign".

But the IF condition requires 3 arguments.

> Invalid input expression. - IF(condition, true_result, else_result)

Ok. This is understandable, but what should I write if it is correct?

I mean something like

```
if(DataName = '12345'){
    DataName = "Main advertising campaign"
}
```

[Image 1. The first column needs to be replaced with the name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8iV6.jpg)

[Image 2. Incorrect formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ijsg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For this case you can better use the "Case when" function.

e.g.

```
case
  when DataName = 123
  then "Main advertising campaign"
  when DataName = 456
  then "Secondary advertising campaign"
  else "Others"
end
```

If your data field "DataName" is formatted as as string, you need to put the 123 in quotes.
Further, it is possible to add another "when then" condition.